# Unzip a file in c# using 7z.exe

Tags: c#, unzip, 7zip

I'm trying to unzip a file from a winform application.
I'm using this code :

```
string dezarhiverPath = @AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\7z.exe";
ProcessStartInfo pro = new ProcessStartInfo();
pro.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
pro.FileName = dezarhiverPath;
pro.Arguments = @" e c:\TEST.ZIP";
Process x = Process.Start(pro);
x.WaitForExit();
```

The code doesn't return error but doesn't anything.
I tried this command also from cmd  :

```
K:\>"C:\Test\7z.exe" e "c:\TEST.ZIP"
```

but in cmd ,I receive this error message :

```
7-Zip cannot find the code that works with archives.
```

Can somebody help me to unzip some files from c# ?

Thanks!

Comment: i could run your command successfully on commandline

Comment: @Jack Incorrect. Note the `@` sign in front of the string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179389/at-sign-in-file-path-string

Comment: I'm using version 4.65.0.0 of 7z.exe on Win XP .What version did you use ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773371/how-to-extract-zip-file-contents-into-a-folder-in-net-4-5

Comment: One issue i see is AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory includes a trailling "\\" so you should remove "\\" from "\\7z.exe".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you bother trying to use the 7z.exe application externally? That is a very kludgy way of doing it. Instead use one of the many libraries at your disposal.

If this is a new application, and you are targeting .NET 4.5, The new [`System.IO.Compression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.aspx) namespace has a [`ZipFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx) class.

Alternatively, [`SharpZipLib`](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) is a GPL library for file compression in .NET.  There are [online samples](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples).

Also available is [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) which is Ms-PL licensed.

Comment: Then I would consider using SharpZipLib or DotNetZip.  [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=.net+zip+library) provides a massive amount of information.

Comment: For sharpZipLib I should add an extern reference ?

Comment: Yes. ["How to use library in C#"](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+library+in+c%23).  [C# Using other people's code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778670/c-sharp-using-others-code/8778720#8778720).

Comment: @user1577242 Using winzip32.exe or any other zip utility externally, when you could just as easily do it the *right* way, and use a library, is just plain absurd.

Comment: DON'T FORGET: need to add a reference to the .NET assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

Answer (score 2):

Hey use this code below , you must have 7zip application in your system .

```
  public void ExtractFile(string source, string destination)
    {
        string zPath = @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe";// change the path and give yours 
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo pro = new ProcessStartInfo();
            pro.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            pro.FileName = zPath;
            pro.Arguments = "x \"" + source + "\" -o" + destination;
            Process x = Process.Start(pro);
            x.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (System.Exception Ex) {
          //DO logic here 
          }
    }
```

to create :

```
public void CreateZip()
{
    string sourceName = @"d:\a\example.txt";
    string targetName = @"d:\a\123.zip";
    ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
    p.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe";
    p.Arguments = "a -tgzip \"" + targetName + "\" \"" + sourceName + "\" -mx=9";
    p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    Process x = Process.Start(p);
    x.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: `pro.CreateNoWindow = true;` seems to successfully do what I thought `pro.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;` was going to do but failed - which is not flash a fleeting CMD prompt on the screen upon running the program.

Answer (score 0):

**Refer Following Code:**

```
using System.IO.Compression;

string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

**Referance Link:**

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/849c4969-24b1-4650-88a5-5169727e527f/

Comment: WHo is ZIPFile?My application doesn't recognize it .

Comment: Downvoted because you merely copy and pasted information from a linked page with no other information. Link-only answers should really be comments.

Comment: I could have also posted only code. But i have taken care to post link for it also , so that he can follow further discussion over there and may get something useful. Ofcourse, its upon you, whome to upvote and whome to downvote.

Comment: Not so. If you had only posted code and no link, then that would have been plagiarism and eligible for deletion.

Comment: if that answer is from stack , then it would be eligible for deletion. Now also you can report this answer if you want. I am confident, will not get deleted.

Comment: No, I said *if you had posted only the code, and not attributed the source with a link*, then it would be [eligible for deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered).

Comment: I know that my friend, i have flaged many of such answers for this purpose.

Comment: Just to make a note..this suffers with the 260 char limit problem.  Other than that, it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SevenZipSharp library

```
using (var input = File.OpenRead(lstFiles[0]))
{
    using (var ds = new SevenZipExtractor(input))
    {
        //ds.ExtractionFinished += DsOnExtractionFinished;

        var mem = new MemoryStream();
        ds.ExtractFile(0, mem);

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(mem))
        {
            var iCount = 0;
            String line;
            mem.Position = 0;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null && iCount < 100)
            {
                iCount++;
                LstOutput.Items.Add(line);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    string fileZip = @"c:\example\result.zip";
    string fileZipPathExtactx= @"c:\example\";
    ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
    p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p.FileName = dezarhiverPath ;
    p.Arguments = "x \"" + fileZip + "\" -o" + fileZipPathExtact;
    Process x = Process.Start(p);
    x.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe can help you.

```
        //You must create an empty folder to remove.
        string tempDirectoryPath = @"C:\Users\HOPE\Desktop\Test Folder\zipfolder";
        string zipFilePath = @"C:\Users\HOPE\Desktop\7za920.zip";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDirectoryPath);
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFilePath, tempDirectoryPath);
```