# Test Zip files in a UNC path using 7za

Tags: c#, process, processstartinfo

Here is my code:

```
        string prova = @"\\10.20.9.1\fold\BCK_Capriata\";
        var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WorkingDirectory = prova,
            WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false 
        };
        startInfo.EnvironmentVariables["Path"] = @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("7z t *.7z");
        process.WaitForExit();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I get this error:

> CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Window directory.

How can I solve this?

EDIT: I understand that I can't start a process in a UNC path and it's better to use directly 7za.exe
But now my question is: How can I tell to 7za that I want to test zip in the UNC folder?

Comment: Why are you starting `cmd` and forcing it to parse another command line rather than just starting `7z` directly?

Comment: because I need to check 7z file in the \\10.20.9.1\fold\BCK_Capriata\ folder

Comment: "UNC paths are not supported." - Period. Pass the path as 7z cmd parameter not as "WorkingDirectory" to the process. And as Damien sais: use 7z.exe, not cmd.exe

Comment: Read my question again. I'm not asking why you're trying to set the working directory. I'm asking why you're running `cmd` rather than running `7z` directly? You seem to be jumping through a number of unnecessary hoops here by *inserting* cmd between your program and the program you *want* to run.

Comment: See https://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unzip a file in c# using 7z.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558363/unzip-a-file-in-c-sharp-using-7z-exe)

Comment: I don't undestand how running directly 7zip I can specify the folder where i want test zip

Answer (score 0):

Run 7z directly rather than trying to invoke it through cmd. As you can see cmd cannot start with UNC paths as the current working directory.

Comment: I don't undestand how running directly 7zip I can specify the folder where i want test zip

Comment: I'd look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558363/unzip-a-file-in-c-sharp-using-7z-exe?noredirect=1&lq=1 if I were you